# Loop over array of Ids and add hours based on ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Data:

```js
[
  { idMembers: [ '62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f' ], hours: 5 },
  {
    idMembers: [ '62d6f80e28907a0385a3a41e', '62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f' ],
    hours: 4
  }
]
```

I need to take each unique id in the idMembers array and add up hours in all objects for that id.
So id '62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f' will have 9 hours after loop and id '62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f' will have 4.

Additional info: The data will be longer with more ids and hours added to this overall array. I would like the end result to look like [{'62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f':9},{'62d6f80e28907a0385a3a41e':4}] but I have no clue on how to obtain this. (So adding up the hours and linking them to that id)

Comment: Why 5 h will be 9? which is the logic?

Comment: So its the same id in both objects, 5+4 = 9

Comment: Would it help to visualize like this?
[
  { idMembers: [ 'Mike' ], hours: 5 },
  {
    idMembers: [ 'Tom', 'Mike' ],
    hours: 4
  }
]

And I need ['Mike':9,'Tom':4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do the job. You have to iterate over every idMember and store in an object (or map) the key/value pair of the hours for each member, adding to the previous value the new hours.

```
let obj = {};
data.forEach(item => {
    for (let memberId of item.idMembers) {
        let oldHours = obj[memberId] ? obj[memberId] : 0;
        obj[memberId] = oldHours + item.hours;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate each object in your data, then iterate the array `idMembers`.

Store each member in another object, check if the id exists, if so increment the value (hours), else set the initial value.

```js
const data = [
  { idMembers: [ '62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f' ], hours: 5 },
  {
    idMembers: [ '62d6f80e28907a0385a3a41e', '62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f' ],
    hours: 4
  }
]

const members = {}

data.forEach( row => {

  for (let member of row.idMembers) {
    if (typeof members[member] !== 'undefined') {
      members[member] += row.hours
    } else {
      members[member] = row.hours
    }
  }
  
})

console.log(members)
```

Answer (score 1):

And one-liner if you don't mind:

```js
const data = [{idMembers:['62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f'],hours:5},{idMembers:['62d6f80e28907a0385a3a41e','62d7001a7446ee76e5e2856f'],hours: 4}];

const result = data.reduce((r, {idMembers: ids, hours: h}) => (ids.forEach(id => r[id] = (r[id] ?? 0) + h), r), {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```